# Why is SQL's BETWEEN inclusive rather than half-open?

Tags: sql

Semi-open (or Half-Open, [Half-Closed](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-ClosedInterval.html), [Half-Bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology)) intervals (`[a,b)`, where `x`belongs to the interval iff `a <= x < b`) are pretty common on programming, as they have many convenient properties.

Can anyone offer a rationale that explains why SQL's `BETWEEN` uses a closed interval (`[a,b]`)? This is esp. inconvenient for dates. Why would you have `BETWEEN` behave like this?

Comment: I'm curious, what convenient properties do they have?

Comment: if it was not inclusive how could you easily query for all last names in the range A to D? or names W to Z?  For numbers between 1 and 10 you can search 0 < n < 11, but for characters you would have to use ASCII numbers? or unicode numbers? Plus, the indexes can easily get you to the start of your data.

Comment: I understand your frustration, (StartDate >= '2010-01-01' and StartDate < '2011-01-01'), works beautifully, to use Between the equivelent would be (StartDate between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31 23:59:59'), both bulky and one needs to know how many days are in Dec.

Comment: @phant0m [a,b) U [c,d) == [a,d). [a:int,b:int) contains exactly b-a elements. Todd's comment shows how they work especially well for dates (which is were I miss them most). Basically, when coding, semiopen intervals tend to be simpler, easier to use and robust.

Comment: The best answer should have referenced objective decision documentation from the people who first specified BETWEEN for SQL, thereby answering Why, rather than the subjective answer selected.

Comment: @Todd 23:59:59 is inaccurate for several reasons. It assumes the system works with seconds; if milliseconds are used, you might end up with a bit less than a year. Also, `between "2008-01-01" and "2008-12-31 23:59:59"` is missing one second, because there was a leap second. It would have to be 23:59:60...

Comment: @basic6 should read my comment again. I am against the between operator. Your point is my point. Using an exclusive second place operand would contain the leap second, which is why I don't use between. It seldom works and confuses users. Go all the way to years: `year(lastDate) between '2007' and '2008'` will cover two years not one.

Comment: Late to the show, but can't help mention that FORTRAN array indices start(ed) at 1, something we're puzzled about today, rather. I guess its a similar thing.-)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think inclusive `BETWEEN` is more intuitive (and apparently, so did the SQL designers) than a semi-open interval. For example, if I say "Pick a number between 1 and 10", most people will include the numbers 1 and 10. The open-ended interval is actually particularly confusing for non-developers because it's asymmetric. SQL is occasionally used by non-programmers to make simple queries, and semi-open semantics would have been *much* more confusing for them.

Comment: Your example focuses on integers, for decimal numbers and other delimited quantities (such as dates), the term between is ambiguous. If I say have you done X between 2012 and 2013, I don't include 2013 (or specifically the day 2013-01-01)

Comment: @Todd Any usage of these terms are ambiguous. That is why mathematicians, scientists, and savvy programmers document their intention as "half-open" or such. I think the point of Oleski’s answer is that SQL was originally intended for end-users rather than programmers (really!). Apparently the SQL designers took a stab at a definition they thought best for that audience. But as the authors of the Question suggests, half-open is almost always better for working with ranges such as spans of time.

Comment: "I think inclusive BETWEEN is more intuitive" is subjective. "SQL is occasionally used by non-programmers to make simple queries" - Non-programmers would equally need to check the spec.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080824/mysql-between-clause-not-inclusive

Comment: The question is also often asked "Pick a number **from** 1 **to** 10" (simply to avoid the obvious ambiguity). As a side note. You say "pick a number between 1 and 10"; most people probably wouldn't choose 1 or 10. _Granted that's more of a psychology issue. :)_ People would still accept 1 and 10 as valid choices (in spite of being semantically incorrect); but that's a result of contextual interpretation ***assuming*** 1 and 10 are valid. If you were to say: "between 13 and 24" and you're more likely to be asked whether 13 and 24 are included.

Comment: i'd like to stress again - "SQL is occasionally used by **non-programmers**", sometimes more often by them than the programmers themselves - for example, sales season for shop owners, targeted advertising campaigns via newspapers and magazines in specific geographical regions.

Answer (score 38):

QUESTION: Why is SQL's BETWEEN inclusive?

ANSWER: Because the SQL language designers made a poor design decision, in that they failed to deliver syntax that would allow developers to specify which of the 4 variants of BETWEEN (closed, semi-open-left, semi-open-right, or open) they'd prefer.

RECOMMENDATION: Unless/until the SQL standard is amended, don't use BETWEEN for dates/times.  Instead get into the habit of coding DATE range comparisons as independent conditions on the start and end boundaries of your BETWEEN range.  This is a bit verbose, but will leave you writing conditions that are intuitive (thus less likely to be buggy) and clear to the database optimizers, allowing for optimal execution plans to be determined and indexes to be used.

For example, if your query is accepting an input day specification and should return all records which fell on that date, you'd code as:

- `WHERE DATE_FIELD >= :dt AND DATE_FIELD < :dt+1`

Trying to write the logic using BETWEEN risks performance issues and/or buggy code.  Three common missteps:

1) `WHERE DATE_FIELD BETWEEN :dt AND :dt+1`

This is almost certainly a bug - user expects to see only records for a particular date, yet one day will wind up with a report containing records from 12:00 a.m. of the next day.

2) `WHERE TRUNC(DATE_FIELD) = :dt`

Gives right answer, but applying the function to DATE_FIELD will render most indexing / statistics useless (though sometimes DBAs will try to help by adding function-based indexes to the date fields - still burning up man-hours and disk space and adding overhead to IUD operations on the table)

3) `WHERE EVENT_DATE BETWEEN :dt AND :dt + 1-1/24/60/60`

Tom Kyte, Oracle guru extraordinaire, recommends this less-than-elegant (IMO) solution. Works great until you're spending all day to find that "1-1/24/06/60" in a query that gives incomplete results... or until you accidentally use it on a TIMESTAMP field.  Plus, it's a bit proprietary; compatible with Oracle's DATE data type (which tracks to the second), but needs to be adjusted to the DATE/TIME precision of different database products.

SOLUTION: Petition the ANSI SQL committee to enhance the SQL language specs by modifying the BETWEEN syntax to support specification of alternatives to the CLOSED/INCLUSIVE default. 
Something like this would do the trick:

> *expr1* BETWEEN  *expr2* [ **INCL[USIVE]** | EXCL[USIVE] ] AND *expr3* [ **INCL[USIVE]** | EXCL[USIVE] ]

Consider how easy it becomes to express `WHERE DATE_FIELD BETWEEN :dt INCLUSIVE AND :dt+1 EXCLUSIVE` (or just `WHERE DATE_FIELD BETWEEN :dt AND :dt+1 EXCL`)

Maybe ANSI SQL:2015?

Comment: This answer is sage advice.

Comment: @KevinKirkPatrick - Great answer! I suggest you also try to find the decision documentation as objective evidence of the original Why.

Comment: I personally like `exp1 BETWEEN exp2 AND exp3 AND exp1 != exp3` that way you get to keep the between operator so you know it's a ranged predicate, and the inequality predicate ensures that it's semi open.

Comment: @Sentinel,  Nice!  I'm not going to declare myself a convert prematurely, but I'll definitely keep this variant in mind for when I next code date-range conditions.  At first blush, it does have a greater linguistic appeal than the exp1 >= exp2 AND exp1 < exp3; and obviously solves issues with BETWEEN equally well.  I'd be interested if any optimizers show greater "understanding" of one variation over the other; certainly, it seems plausible that yours may yield better results in that regard as well (though frankly, I'd be pretty disappointed in the optimizer that treated them differently)

Comment: @KevinKirkpatrick I've never profiled them to ascertain if there are any differences, and I too would be disappointed if there were.

Comment: Sadly ANSI SQL does not evolves so quickly like programming languages like C#, Java or Javascript, but these INCLUSIVE and EXCLUSIVE keywords must be awesome to have.

Comment: The problem of option 3 is that some databases or field types have milliseconds precision or even more, and then you have again a little gap (this time of missed results)

Answer (score 9):

Both inclusive (`a <= x <= b`) and exclusive (`a < x < b`) are about equally common, so when making the standards they simply had to pick one.  "Between" in common English is typically inclusive, and a SQL statement is meant to read similar to an English sentence, so inclusive was a sensible choice.

Comment: Actually usage in English is even more mixed as you left out Half-Open. When we say "lunch is between noon and 1 PM" we mean half-open in that you are expected back in class / work at the moment of 13:00:00.000, with the break going up to **but not including** the first moment of the one-o-clock hour. `a <= x < b` is Half-Open.

Comment: @BasilBourque: This may be due to infinite precision - e.g. lunch is between noon and 12:59:99.9999999999999....

Comment: @Brendan Yes, you are making my point. The infinite (or ambiguous) precision is one of the problems that is handled by using the half-open approach to defining a span of time. The point here is that in English conversation we intuitively handle open and closed (as mentioned in this answer) as well as half-open ranges without much thought. Each approach serves a purpose. That is why the SQL definition of BETWEEN is less than optimal. Ideally, SQL would follow the [suggestion by KevinKirkpatrick](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/262025/34735).

Comment: SQL is supposed to be English-like, and although inclusive and exclusive may be equally common, it's a query language for analysts and programmers. As a programmer, I think it's defined wrong, but that doesn't really matter, I just avoid using "BETWEEN" anyway. Not a big deal.

Comment: it's just weird that for `ORDER BY` there are various variants like `NULLS FIRST` and `NULLS LAST` but nobody thought about a `BETWEEN x AND y NONINCLUSIVE` (not saying that anyone here is responsible for this though)

Answer (score 5):

The operator isn't called `∩[a,b)`, it's called `BETWEEN`, so it's considerably more appropriate for its semantics to be those of the **English phrase** "is between" than those of the mathematical predicate "is in semi-open interval".

Comment: One needs to consider all applications, not just English applications for Integer sets. "between 1 and 10", "between noon and 1pm", "between 1.0 and 5.0" (grams). "between 5.50 and 10.30" (dollars). Continuous quantities would be logically (Englishly) assumed to be exclusive.

Comment: The problem is that the `BETWEEN` operator ***doesn't*** use the semantics of the English phrase "is between". In English "between" is the time, space or interval _that separates_ things (i.e. it's _exclusive_). If you try to kick a goal, the ball has to go between the posts to score. If you hit the post failing to pass between them - no score for you.

Comment: @CraigYoung as the accepted answer suggests (and I agree), " if I say "Pick a number between 1 and 10", most people will include the numbers 1 and 10 [in their range of possible answers]". In a *spatial* domain I agree with you, but for numbers I'd say it's different. Better for [english.se] than here though!

Comment: @AakashM My point is that you've made a claim about the English language which is simply false by dictionary definition of the word "between", to justify programming semantics. The fact that there's a common understanding of the phrase "between 1 and 10" has less to do with the meaning of "between" and more to do with the positions 1 and 10 hold in the decimal number system. The human brain's "auto-correct" ignores that "between" excludes end points in this case because it seems ridiculous to mean "from 2 to 9". Try the same with "between 13 and 24". Or even "between 0 and 11".

Comment: Between you and me, categorical claims about natural languages are usually unsafe.

Comment: @AakashM Don't worry, we can keep your dubious categorical claims about English semantics _between_ us. ;)